# How to get changes in XSD file affect the related CS file?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've created an .xsd file and then used XSD.exe to generate the .cs file (I've used xsd.exe /dataset mySchema.xsd). All is working well but suddenly, I need to add a new field to my xsd.

Do I have to remove the .xsd file from the project, generate and new .cs file using XSD.exe and then add it again or is there an automatic way for VS2010 to update the .cs when I do the change to the xsd through the schema explorer?

Thanks!

Comment: This one of the many things XSD2Code can do. http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

Comment: XSD2Code is a nice app but my code is already using the xsd.exe method. Changing it all now to fit xsd2code would take lots of time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simples solution with your vs2010 project is to include your mySchema.xsd-file as a dataset into the project. If you change the xsd via code- or xsd-editor vs2010 will regenerate regenerate the cs dataset if dataset is set up correctly.

The simplest way to try this out is using the wizzard to add a new dataset.

<strike>(note i havent tried this with vs 2010 but it worked perfectly with vs2002, vs2003, vs2005 and vs2008)</strike>

[update]
It works with vs2010 if xsd-file-property customtool = 'MSDataSetGenerator' is set

Comment: I did add the .xsd and the .cs files to the project and they are added correctly I guess since the .cs file is nested under the .xsd file and the .xsd file has this dataset symbol near it. The only way I manage to edit the .xsd file is through editing its code(for example, adding a new tag <xs:element name="Quantity" type="xs:double"/>. I can see the change applied well to the schema but not to the .cs file...

Comment: Oh man, that's great! but still there's one small problem: the generated .designer.cs class name is always "NewDataSet" although my .xsd file name is something else. Since I have 10 different xsd files, they all get the same class name. Do you have an idea how to work this one out? Thanks anyway and I promise to give you the rating once I get to 15 points(can't up rate yet...).

Comment: Never mind, got that solved as well. Just added "id" attribute to the header tag and it fixed the problem. Thanks again, I've seen that "custom tool" property before. Great help!

Comment: Small correction (edit not working after 5 minutes). The id was added to the schema tag. and of course I meant that I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a Pre-build event with a line like this:

```
"$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\@InstallationFolder)bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\xsd.exe" "$(ProjectDir)MyFile.xsd"
```

This generates a .cs file every time (before) the project is built. It's a hassle, but it works. And if I'm right about this, the project isn't rebuilt if no changes are made to it.

Xsd2Code wasn't an option for me as I needed many xsd's to be handled and xsd.exe allows me to do this. However, you do end up with 1 giant .cs file so it may be necessary to extract any common types so they're not created twice.

If I didn't do that, it would create the same type with a slightly different name, for instance 'Signature', 'Signature1', 'Signature2', etc...